# CSS Grid: min & max values with column width fitting content when content > min

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to get the same behaviour as `fit-content`, but with a `min` that could be set (`fit-content` min is 0)

If the content is **less** than my min column value, my column's width should be the min width:

|my content____|

If the content is **more** than my min column value and **less** than my max, the column should fits to content's width:

|my very long content|

If my content is **more** than my max column value, the content should go wrap:

|my very, very, very long|

|content_____________|

I tried different combinations of `minmax` with no success.

`grid-template-columns: minmax(xxx, xxx);`

Can this be achieved?

Comment: if I may, why not use *auto*?

Comment: I haven't been able to use auto to solve my case. Do you mean using auto in `minmax`, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: *auto* instead of *minmax*

Comment: so regardless of the *content* you want to set a *minimum* and *maximum* for a *grid item*?

Comment: I'm building a `TreeView`, and the layout I describe is for each `node`. For aesthetic reasons, it makes sense to have a min and a max for each `node`. Worst case, I'll use `fit-content` which is the closest I got to what I want, with no min. The `node`'s CSS is more complex, there are more columns, but I'm only showing the minimum here, stripped down to 1 column.

Comment: You should add a minimal code example to better show what you are asking.

Comment: I feel stupid now. `minmax(auto, 200px)` works. I had to delete my cache a few times, like chrome wasn't doing the job.